# MongoDB autoresync stale data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

MongoDB configuration has a param called "autoresync".

This is what it says:
Automatically resync if slave data is stale
autoresync

So if we enable this parameter, when one of the secondaries go into RECOVERING state, can it auto heal MongoDB non primary members who have stale data and unable to replicate data. Some times we see data is too stale. So if we enable this param, can it automatically heal and bring it to good state.

Answer (score 0):

That parameter is "legasy" and has not been supported for... Long time. It was when there was master-slave paradigm in the MongoDB.

With current versions of MongoDB, secondaries always recover (auto heal), IF primary have opLog what is big enough to cover that "missing" data.

So, if your secondary cannot replicate/recover, check that your PRIMARY node opLog is big enough. [Resize opLog without reboot](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/replSetResizeOplog/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.replSetResizeOplog)

To see how long time your opLog can cover, use command [db.getReplicationInfo.timeDiff](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.getReplicationInfo/)

Comment: I am trying to find documentation that suggests that this field/config param is very old. I can't find any. Can you please help.

Comment: Make google search "mongodb master slave outdated" and you find lots of documents that tell you it was used before replica sets.